# SQL result from a research from different lines

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL table :

```
name  | id_photo
================
word1 | 38    
word2 | 38
word7 | 39
word1 | 31
word2 | 31
```

And I would like to research all the id_photo such as name = word1 AND name = word2
for example is this case I would like to have as a return 38,31

Can somebody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID_PHOTO
FROM tableNAME
WHERE name IN ('word1','word2')
GROUP BY ID_PHOTO
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

if unique key was not specified on name for each `id_photo`, use `distinct` inside `COUNT`

```
SELECT ID_PHOTO
FROM tableNAME
WHERE name IN ('word1','word2')
GROUP BY ID_PHOTO
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries included*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6377/1)

Comment: thanks a lot @John Woo !!!! please what is the prurpose of HAVING COUNT( * ) =2 ?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT( * ) =2` counts the number of instances of `ID_PHOTO` [**SEE THIS**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6377/3)